# debugInfoEnabled for Angular 1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, internet-explorer-8, backport

Angular 1.3 introduced a new [`debugInfoEnabled()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider#debugInfoEnabled) method that can provide a boost in performance if called with `false` in the [application config function](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#disabling-debug-data):

```
myApp.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
}]);
```

Also, Angular 1.3 dropped IE8 support. And this is a problem for me, my application have to run on IE8. Hence, I cannot upgrade to angular 1.3 and have to live with 1.2.

Is there a way to achieve the same functionality with angular 1.2?

In particular, at least a part of what `debugInfoEnabled()` does:

- prevent creation of `ng-scope`/`ng-isolated-scope` CSS classes while creating new scopes
- do not attach binding data and ng-class CSS class to elements with ngBind, ngBindHtml or {{...}} interpolations

<sup>As one possible option, I can fork the angularjs repository and backport the feature back to 1.2. Then, use the fork maintaining updates from the upstream.</sup>

Would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: what is the exact version of angular you're using? is it 1.2.7 or less than it

Comment: @pankajparkar trying to stick with latest `1.2.*`. Currently `1.2.28`. Thanks.

Comment: try app.config(function($logProvider){
  $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
}); inside you app

Comment: Here's a build of Angular 1.3 which will work with IE8 https://github.com/fergaldoyle/angular.js-ie8-builds

Comment: @Fergal wow, appreciate that. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the underlying DOM `setAttribute` method to prevent the default behavior. I've edited the plunker in the other answer:

http://plnkr.co/edit/cMar0d9IbalFxDA6AU3e?p=preview

to do the following:

- Clone the DOM `setAttribute` prototype method
- Override it with a check for `ng` debug attributes
- Return false for `ng` debug attributes
- Return as normal otherwise

Use it as follows:

```
/* Clone the original */
HTMLElement.prototype.ngSetAttribute = HTMLElement.prototype.setAttribute;

/* Override the API */
HTMLElement.prototype.setAttribute = function(foo, bar) {
/* Define ng attributes */ 
var nglist = {"ng-binding": true, "ng-scope":true,"ng-class":true,"ng-isolated-scope":true};

console.log([foo,bar]);

/* Block ng attributes; otherwise call the clone */
if (nglist[foo]) 
  return false; 
else if (JSON.stringify(nglist).match(foo) )
  return false;
else
  return this.ngSetAttribute(foo, bar);
}
```

Replace `HTMLElement` with `Element` for IE8.

**References**

- [CSS classes used by angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/css-styling#!)
- [Prototypes, Constructor Functions, and Taxidermy](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2013/07/29/prototypes-constructor-functions-and-taxidermy/)
- [AngularJS IE8 Shim](https://github.com/NantHealth/AngularJS-IE8-Shim)
- [AngularJS IE8 Builds](https://github.com/fergaldoyle/angular.js-ie8-builds)
- [Document Object Model Prototypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282900)
- [Document Object Model Prototypes, Part 2: Accessor (getter/setter) Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd229916)
- [What's New in Internet Explorer 9](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974378)

Answer (score 1):

You can try disable it by mentioning `$logProvider.debugEnabled(true);` inside your angular configuration.
In order to get effect of `debugEnabled` setting, You need ensure that while doing log use `$log` provider.

**Sample Code**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.config(function($logProvider){
  $logProvider.debugEnabled(false);
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $log ) {
  $scope.name = 'Hello World!';
  $scope.testModel = {name: "test"};
  //console.log('This will show log even if debugging is disable');
  $log.debug('TEST Log');
});
```

Here is **[Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/ckTaqG?p=preview)**

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, but I think it would [only turn off debug log messages](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d3b1f502e3099d91042a1827a006ad112ea67d36/src/ng/log.js#L54)..